# Print window is not working in ASP.NET MVC using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have opened print window in another tab but from where it is opened I have given Back button no any action performed for back button instead I have click on any action new opened print window i.e any action i.e print , cancel or close window.
If I perform any one of above action on new opened print window then only back button is working correctly which is prsent in where the print button is present
in PrintPreview window Two button

1. Print
2. Back

   ```
   <input  id="PrintMasterList" value="Print"/>           
   <input  value="Back" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("index")'"/>
   ```

and the PrintPreview.cshtml page for print button is

the div   `#MasterListPrintPreview` present on `PrintPreview.cshtml` page

```
<div class="span8" id="MasterListPrintPreview" style="">

$("#PrintMasterList").click(function () {       
    var divContents = $("#MasterListPrintPreview").html();
    printWindow = window.open('', '','');
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Orders</title>');
    printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    printWindow.document.write(divContents);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.document.close();
});
```

So what I need is if I click on print, print is open and then I didn't perform any action in print window then if I click on back button it  should work.

Any thoughts

Comment: add printWindow.focus(); before printWindow.print();

Comment: Used  printWindow.focus(); before  printWindow.print();  then alson its not working

Comment: Grammer correction and code formatted